# How to render a Google Slides presentation via API and control / move slides?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to render a Google Slides presentation in my web app and control it (move slides) using buttons on my web app.
If I embed it using iframe, then I can't send key/mouse events to that iframe since it's [not the same origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65511823/1380370), and I don't want to use Google's embedded control bar, since I need my own custom controls.

Therefor I'm trying to achieve this using the Google Slides API.
I found some relevant APIs like [this one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide?hl=en#move(Integer)) but I don't understand whether I can render the presentation in my DOM.
Is it possible to render an existing presentation and navigate / control it using the API?

Comment: That `move` API is an "update" operation that reorders the presentation. The Google Slides API isn't a rendering / drawing interface - it's a crud interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, do you want to control the actual presentation via API? Something like a automatic presentation in an iframe? What exactly are you trying to render in an iframe right now? Can you share whatever code you have? My first instinct is that you can't do what you want with the API, but maybe an Apps Script web app could be a possibility, but I'm not sure that this is what you want.

Comment: @iansedano I want to render an existing presentation based on a url given by the user, but control it using my own buttons (so that the user won't have to focus on the iframe or use the embedded control navigation in order to move slides - but only click on my buttons which are outside the iframe). So yes, I want to control the presentation navigation using code. The problem is that if I render it as an embedded iframe, I can't interact with it programmatically.

Comment: I also looked for a similar solution for rendering & navigating a PPT presentation uploaded by the user as an alternative, but figured it will be even more complicated to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

#### There is a feature request for that API functionality

https://issuetracker.google.com/36760981

Go give it a ☆ if you want to see it implemented.

<sup>Please do not just comment "+1" -  a star is enough</sup>

#### Workaround

- Export it using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export).
- With the resulting images or PDF, create your own slide show functionality (I know, not ideal...but possible)

Comment: Thanks! I starred it. It could be super useful for many use cases. Do you maybe know what are the timelines for these type of feature requests? can I get any estimations?

Comment: No ETA I'm afraid, I wouldn't count on it if you need something urgent!

Comment: Really hoping they decide to take this on, however I can see reasons why they wouldn't